# Unable to retrive data attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select option dropdown like:

```
 <select name="futsalSelect" id="futsalSelect" class="form-control">
     <option data-timezone="MST" value="1" selected="">Sample futsal One</option>
     <option data-timezone="EST" value="3">Sample futsal Three</option>
 </select>
```

Now, I want to retrive that `data-timezone` value whenever I change that select option.

So, I tried with:

```
 $("#futsalSelect").change(function() {
     futsal_id = $(this).val();

     timezone = $(this).attr("data-timezone");
     console.log(timezone);  //undefined

     $("#futsalTimezone").text(timezone);
 });
```

But, it is returning undefined.

Comment: data-timezon is in your option tag, your looking for it in your select tag by utilizing `this` context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to read the data attribute of the option, not of select.
This will do it:

```
$('#futsalSelect').change(function() {         
     futsal_id = $(this).val();

     timezone = $(this).find('option:selected').data('timezone');
     console.log(timezone);  //undefined

     $('#futsalTimezone').text(timezone);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is returning `undefined` because `this` inside the function refers to the main `#futsalSelect` element and not the selected option. To get the desired value, do it like this:

```
 $("#futsalSelect").change(function() {

     timezone = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-timezone");
     console.log(timezone);

     $("#futsalTimezone").text(timezone);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

use the option:selected selector:

```js
 $("#futsalSelect").change(function() {
     futsal_id = $("#futsalSelect option:selected" ).val();

     timezone = $("#futsalSelect option:selected" ).attr("data-timezone");
     console.log(timezone);  //undefined

     $("#futsalTimezone").text(timezone);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="futsalSelect" id="futsalSelect" class="form-control">
     <option data-timezone="MST" value="1" selected="">Sample futsal One</option>
     <option data-timezone="EST" value="3">Sample futsal Three</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to get the value from select data-timezone.
you must take it to **option inside select**.

hope it helps.